# Oracle packages in version control?

Tags: database, oracle

Lucky me, I have to work with Oracle. And packages.

I have a package that a lot of different developers are touching and it's scaring me. Is it possible to put a package inside of Version Control? Is there some kind of software out there that already does this? If not, is there some kind of export procedure? Can I just grab a file off of a file system?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706026/how-do-you-work-on-oracle-packages-in-a-collaborative-version-controlled-environ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111852/tools-to-work-with-stored-procedures-in-oracle-in-a-team

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are they inputting it? The way we used to work at my last job is editing a text file, and loading it with SQL*Plus. You can just put that source file under version control.

The source must be between "`CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYPACKAGE AS`" and "`END;`" followed by a single slash on a line of its own ("/"); and ditto for "PACKAGE BODY" instead of "PACKAGE".

And yes, there's a way to pull the source out of Oracle. It's in a table, line by line, look up [ALL_SOURCE](http://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/8.3/oracompat/EnterpriseDB_OraCompat_EN_8.3-239.htm) and USER_SOURCE. You can pull it out with a query like

```
SELECT TEXT FROM ALL_SOURCE
WHERE TYPE='PACKAGE BODY'
  AND NAME='MYPACKAGE' 
  AND OWNER='MYPACKAGEOWNER'
ORDER BY LINE
```

(untested as I no longer have access to Oracle) and ditto for the 'PACKAGE'.

I think it's best to load it again into Oracle using SQL*Plus; make sure to set "SCAN OFF".

Comment: Just wanted to add:  If your developers are just editing & recompiling the package in Oracle without having a source file under version control, you are very right to be concerned.  They probably like this because it's easy using TOAD or similar tools, but I dislike it as a way to maintain code.

Comment: And when you roll out a new version of your application, always use the latest packages from version control.  Your developers would not accept less for their java, c#, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We have a database level trigger to capture changes to packages and save the source in a seperate table.  It's not as good as version control, but at least you know when something changes and can retrieve it if a later change tramples on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download sql developer for free: http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/files/what_is_sqldev.html. It integrates with subversion and cvs.

There is also a Visual Studio plugin (http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html). I don't know whether you use Visual Studio or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://code.google.com/p/oracle-ddl2svn/ version control for Oracle

Answer (score -1):

Take also a look at [this link](http://deltasql.sourceforge.net). It's a PHP/mySQL versioning tool which works with any database type and is fairly simple to learn.